# RabbitMQ Question - Is there a way to print log message to console?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am running RabbitMQ on windows 7  ( currently for debug reasons).
I want to see the messages on the open console each time I send a message.
Is there a way to rout the logs to the open console? 
10x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a logger application that connects to rabbitMQ creates a queue that consumes all messages sent from the broker, this works best with a fanout exchange or a topic exchange where you can set the routing key to be # (ie for everything).  As you consume each message you can print it to the console or to a log.  This will be separate from your apps and you can easily turn it of or on when ever you want.  It should not slow down noticably the current system by adding a single extra queue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in, the programming language you are using to Publish and consume messages from RabbitMQ.